# Insert row if ID exists in another table

Tags: sql

I wanted to check if there was a way to insert a row, but only if a ID already existed in another table. For example:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (carID) 
SELECT carID FROM table2 WHERE table1.carID IN table2.carID
```

Basically, I only would like to insert carID in table1 if that ID can be found in table2.

Comment: You want to insert all IDs from `table2` into `table1`? Or do you want to insert a given ID, e.g. 123, into `table1` only if it is in `table2` and nothing otherwise?

Comment: db dialect/vendor?

Comment: I only want to insert a row with carID if that carID exists in table2.

Comment: But the ID you actually want to insert is given ("from outside")?

Comment: @stickybit yes, sort of. The IDs I want to insert should already exist in another table.

Comment: Yeah I get that. But... Do you have an ID, e.g. 123 and now you want to insert that into `table1` if a row with 123 exists in `table2` or don't you have a specific ID but jsut want to insert *all* IDs in `table2` into `table1`. There's a difference... And if you got a given ID, say 123, what to do if it exists in `table2` more than once? Insert into `table1` only one time or as often as it it is present in `table2`?

Comment: Oh, I get what you're saying. Yeah, I wasn't looking for a specific ID, though I suppose that would be important. Good point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `EXISTS`:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (carID)
SELECT t2.carID
FROM table2 t2
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table1 t1 WHERE t1.carID = t2.carID);
```

Comment: What does the "SELECT 1" do in this case? Of could it be anything since it's a subquery?

Comment: @MiguelStevens Good question, and the answer depends on the database vendor.  On Postgres, even `SELECT FROM` (with nothing actually after select) is allowed.

Answer (score 1):

You can add to `table1` all `carID`s that exist in `table2`:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (carID) 
SELECT carID FROM table2
```

If you want to apply a condition you can add a `WHERE` part.

Answer (score 1):

you could use `in`

```
    INSERT INTO table1 (carID) 
    SELECT carID FROM table2 WHERE table2.carID IN (select carID from table1 where carID is not null)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just select the ID from `table2` checking for the given ID in the `WHERE` clause. If there is no matching row in `table2`, the `SELECT` returns the empty set and nothing is inserted into `table1`. If there are rows with that ID, they get selected and inserted. If an ID can occurs multiple times in `table2` but you only want to insert it once, you can use `DISTINCT`.

```
INSERT INTO table1
            (carid) 
            SELECT DISTINCT
                   carid
                   FROM table2
                        WHERE carid = <given carid>;
```